# How does importing a module in another file in a Databricks Repos work?

Tags: databricks, databricks-repos

I am using databricks repos

I have two files,
My function in a file called func.py in another folder called folder1

```
def lower_events(df):

 return df.withColumn("event",f.lower(f.col("event")))
```

My main notebook in which I am calling the lower_events

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, col, lower
import sys
 
sys.path.append("..")
from folder1 import func
 
df_clean = func.lower_events(df)
```

This returns an error

```
NameError: name 'f' is not defined
```

But this is working

```
def lower_events(df):

 import pyspark.sql.functions as f
 from pyspark.sql.functions import col, when

 return df.withColumn("event",f.lower(f.col("event")))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is correct as each individual Python module has its own imports and doesn't refer to the imports done in the main module or other modules (see [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/import.html) for more details).

So your `func.py` should contain imports somewhere - not necessary in the function itself, it could be in the top-level of the file:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, when

def lower_events(df):
 return df.withColumn("event",f.lower(f.col("event")))
```

P.S. You also may not need `sys.path.append("..")` - Databricks Repos will automatically add root of the repository to the `sys.path`.